# How to filter files in sonar SCM?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have installed a CI environment for my PHP project.

I use jenkins + sonar + Gitlab.

All things seem great until build a jenkins job.

The error info is

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2:03.218s
Final Memory: 345M/456M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to blame file src/apps/conf.php. No blame info at line 1. Is file commited?
10:21:17.165 INFO  - Author: PersonIdent[Not Committed Yet, , Wed Feb 4 10:21:17 2015 +0800]
ERROR:
```

I find sonar **SCM-Activity-Plugin** report this bug.

The **conf.php** file is my config file and can not push to Gitlab.

So, Is there a way to ask **SCM-Activity-Plugin** filter these config files?

thanks a lot!

Comment: If you cannot push it to remote, why not add this file into .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the file from sonar analysis might help.

Login to sonar using admin or user that have got administrative rights in the project.
Open the project and select “Settings” from “Project Configuration”.

There click on “Exclusions” link and take “File” tab.
Under “Source File Exclusions” give your file as src/apps/conf.php